# Is this database design applicable to have subqestions?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: EmployeeID, Name, OrgCode
Department Table: OrgCode, DepartName
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, RespondantID, QuestionsAnswersID
Questions Table: QuestionID, Question
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuestionsAnswers Table: ID, QuestionID, AnswerID
```

Each question has different multiple choices. Besides that,  I am thinking to add sub-questions under the question. Most of

the questions have the same choices such as (Agree, Disagree). I want to write the query that shows the question including

its sub-questions with all of its choices and the number of participants in each choice even if it is zero.

**I am not sure if the Questions Table will help me in inserting sub-questions under any question. Is that design applicable? What do you recommend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current Question table, you can't have sub questions. You may try having an ID representing sub questions (like Question has ID 2, and Then sub question against that has ID 2A or something like that), but this design may fail and it depends on your computation of ID, also you can't be sure of level of sub questions.

A better approach would be to have [Parent-Child Dimension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846.aspx) for self referencing relation. You may have:

> Questions Table: QuestionID, Question, ParentID

where ParentID is the ID of some question. If it is null then the question is not the sub question of any question. You may also see [Employee-Manager Relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php) for recursive relationships, This may help you to better understand your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help and could you please provide me with an example to your approach?

Comment: @user1395782, check the link for Employee Manager Relationship, its kind of same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well no, there is nowhere to specify the parent of a subquestion (or the children of a question).

Possible ways would be:
1. Add a parent column Questions table where you put the id of the parent question.
2. Add a subquestions column to Questions table, and store the subquestion ids as array / json . I think this might make it difficult to do queries.
3. Create new table subquestions - with 2 columns  for every subquestion you create.